# Creating a COM class capable of for each looping using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, com

Excel/VBA is used very extensively in the organization I work in. To make things a little easier I'm working on some widely usable COM classes in .NET/VS2010 to use in VBA.

However I can't seem to implement a COM object that supports for each looping. How can this behavior be implemented?

To specify a bit:

In many cases I'll create some class (lets call it SomeClass) and an accompanying specialized collection class (lets call it SomeClassCollection). In pure .NET this is often not necessary as I can simply create the necessary specialized extensions to a generic container (e.g. List(Of SomeClass)). In VBA/COM however i need to create a separate specialized collection class for most custom classes.

For me the most obvious way to create the SomeClassCollection COM compliant object is to inherit some generic .NET collection, e.g. List(Of SomeClass) and then create add specialized functions as well as make basic functions and properties COM visible (e.g. Add, Remove, Count etc.)

Because I'm inheriting a .NET collection where for each is supported (in .NET) i was thinking that it might be possible to transfer this capability to the COM collection class as well in some way (cf. Worksheets, Workbooks etc. collections in Excel that support for each).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to implement a COM visible class which exposes a method with signature `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` and mark it with DISPID of -4 (which is DISPID_NEWENUM)

It is [explained in more details here](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/exposing-an-enumerator-from-managed-code-to-com/)